# Updating Custom Button Image after UITableView being scrolled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uikit

I am working on accessing a custom check box which I have already utilized in my project as a custom button, and trying to access it in my table view cell.

Currently, it is prompting the button correctly, and works just fine, except for the case when I scroll my tableview, and then make any further changes on the button (either checkin, or checkout), the button image will overlay the older image and not update the draw.

I am just curious, is there any fix for this?

My code looks something like this:

my code for cellForRowAtIndexPath looks like this:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

                static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableCell";

                CustomTableCell *cell = (CustomTableCell *)
                [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

                if (cell == nil) {

                    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableCell" 
                    owner:self options:nil];

                     cell = tableCell;

                    self.tableCell = nil;
                }

                CheckBox *chkBox = [[CheckBox alloc] init];
                chkBox.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, -10.0, 50.0, 70.0);
                [cell.contentView addSubview:chkBox];
                [chkBox release];

                cell.modelLabel.text = 
  [[[[[self regData] ShoppingCart] objectForKey:@"Cart"] 
  valueForKey:@"Model"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                // Configure the cell...
                return cell;
            }
```

I haven't implemented the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method yet as that method is suppose to take the viewer to newer screen with more information.

Comment: can you please post part of code for cellForrowatindexPath and heightForrowAtIndexPath? from the description you gave it seems that your custom cell has multiple overlapping views or there is problem with reusing cell content.

Comment: I updated my question with the code Chatur.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is adding the Checkbox every time you display a cell, regardless of whether it's a new or reused cell.

You don't want to do this every time:

```
CheckBox *chkBox = [[CheckBox alloc] init];
chkBox.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, -10.0, 50.0, 70.0);
[cell.contentView addSubview:chkBox];
[chkBox release];
```

Only do this if it's a new cell... however by adding the checkbox as a subview and then releasing it, you're losing access to it anyway. To access it you'll need to iterate the subviews of the cell, find the one of type checkbox and then see if it's checked.
It would be better if your CustomTableCell had a Checkbox property that you set, so you could easily access it.

Comment: Do you think this makes more sense?  if (cell == nil) {

                    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableCell" 
                    owner:self options:nil];

                     cell = tableCell;

                     CheckBox *chkBox = [[CheckBox alloc] init];
                chkBox.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, -10.0, 50.0, 70.0);
                [cell.contentView addSubview:chkBox];
                [chkBox release];
  } I can embedd button only when the cell is equal to nil right? So that way it won't keep on creating the checkbox. I can go ahead and set the property also.